# How to store json array elements into one table in sqlite db

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I want to store this data into one table through one pojo class.so by this understanding I can relate it to two seprate tables.But as per requirement I have to save it in one table. I don't want to save it in to two seprate tables.How to achieve this ? (I just need the logic here.. I'm not expecting code leve)

EDIT PART

As you can see, there is no common parameter to relate this data in future from to seperate table

```
 {
        "createDate": 1339957800000,
        "modifyDate": 1341197519000,
        "createdBy": "aaa",
        "modifiedBy": "ddd",
        "status": "A",
        "description": "ffff",
        "parentId": null,
        "sourceId": null,
        "source_Field1": null,
        "source_Field2": null,
        "source_Field3": null,
        "source_Field4": null,
        "source_Field5": null,
        "parentKey": null,
        "parentValue": null,
        "genericMasterView":
        {
            "key": "MOD_ONE",
            "value": "195"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Any reason why it has to be a requirement of one table - from this its just a one to many relationship over 2 tables?

Comment: @cryptic this json have relation of one to many and should be stored in two table but also can be stored in one table but with redundant data if you want to i can demonstrate.

Comment: @cryptic: you can convert the json to string and save it in the db. While fetching, get the string data and convert it to the jsonobject :)

Comment: I have implemented volley here  

 if(response!=null)
                {
                    if(response.length>0)
                    {
                        DbHelper.getDatabase(SplashActivity.this).insertMasterData(Arrays.asList(response));
                    }
                }

Usingt pojo class. Keeping similar name with respect to json respone body

Comment: @rana_sadam Please give your suggestion..Thanks

Comment: You could use RealmDB instead...

Answer (score 1):

First Suggestion is create a table with 2 column one is Key and other is value Key contain any unique string key that represent ur data and value contain your json feed as string

[image: Feed table screen shot]

Other suggestion is to create a table with all keys as columns but the key **genericMasterView** would accommodate in 2 column **genericMasterView_KEY** and **genericMasterView_value** parse your json and enter the records in database. Hope this would help.